# If img alt tag includes 'sold' find the next matching class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find the next matching class and remove it with a CSS `display` of `none` if the `img` within each `.col-sm-4` has a substring of `sold` in its `alt` attribute.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.col-sm-4').each(function() {
    if ($("img [alt=sold]")) {
        $(this).next('.quick-enquire a').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
  <a href="http://localhost:8888/?attachment_id=420" class="thumbnail img-thumbnail" data-slb-group="28_auto_1" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-internal="420">
    <img width="300" height="300" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/img.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="sold" />
  </a>
  <div class="pic-options">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <span class="quick-enquire"><a href="#">Enquire about this painting</a></span>
      <span id="isSold">sold</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```css
$('.col-sm-4').each(function() {
    $("img[alt*='sold']")    /* image having 'sold' substring in its alt attr */
    .parent().next()         /* go UP one level then match the next element   */
    .find('.quick-enquire')  /* find the `.quick-enquire` */
    .children('a')           /* select its <a> child      */
    .css('display', 'none'); /* .hide() the child         */
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been struggling with that for hours! Worked a charm...cheers!